# problema en resultado de método recursivo

Tags: c++, codeblocks

sera que me puedan explicar cuál es le problema para que este método arroje falso a pesar de que es true lo que debe de indicar

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string verificarIdentificacion(string[][2], int, string, string);


string verificarIdentificacion(string matriz[2][2], int contador, string identificacion, string encontrado){
    
     
    if(contador <3){
        
        if(matriz[contador][0] == identificacion){
        
           encontrado = "true";
           cout<<matriz[contador][0]<<endl;
        
        }else{
        
            verificarIdentificacion(matriz,contador+1,identificacion,encontrado);
        
        }
    }
    
    
    return encontrado;
    
}


int main()
{
    string matriz[2][2] = {{"1","hola"},{"3","que"}};
    
    int contador=1;
    
    string encontrado = "false";
    
    string existe = verificarIdentificacion(matriz,contador,"1",encontrado);
    
    cout<<existe;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

estoy creando este código para una tarea más complicada

ocupo hacer un método recursivo que evalué si se encuentra la identificación de una empresa entre las almacenadas

**pasa que solo funciona cuando le ingreso "3" pero si le ingreso "1" a pesar de que debe arrojar true no funciona** arroja falso, de verdad que le agradezco al que me ayude

Comment: Si quieres que las variables de tipo `bool` se impriman como `true` y `false` en un stream, puedes hacerlo con [`boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función siempre devuelve el parámetro `encontrado`, que en la función `main` recibe el valor de `"false"`.

Por otro lado, el parámetro `encontrado` no es necesario y la recursión está mal aplicada.

- Necesitas un caso base. No haber encontrado un elemento que satisfaga la condición es un buen caso base.
- Para lo anterior también debes saber cuándo la recursión debe parar. Con un contador es más sencillo contar hacia atrás. Si llega a -1 significa que terminó.

  El -1 es conveniente ya que la primera posición de los arreglos es el 0.

  En caso de contar hacia delante deberías agregar un parámetro para saber hasta qué número debe contar.
- El caso diferente ya lo tienes. Solo falta que la función se llame a sí misma y se devuelva el resultado.

El código queda así:

```
string verificarIdentificacion(string matriz[2][2], int contador, string identificacion){
    // Caso base
    if (contador < 0)
        return "false";
        
    if (matriz[contador][0] == identificacion){
        cout << matriz[contador][0] << endl;
        return "true";
    }
        
    return verificarIdentificacion(matriz, contador - 1, identificacion);
}
```

---

Quizá creíste que al asignar el parámetro `encontrado` estabas modificando la variable homónima de la función `main`.

En C++ las variables contienen su valor. No una referencia, como sucede en Java, C#, Javascript o Python.

Entonces, si lo que quieres es modificar una variable externa, puedes usar un [puntero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer), o mejor aún, una [referencia](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

Comment: funciona con 1, pero ahora tira falso cuando busco el 3

Comment: no entiendo que deberia hacer entonces

Comment: @Esther A mí si me funciona https://tio.run/##hZDPboQgEMbvPMWEXjRhs257VHvpqc@w8TAF3JIoWMAe1vjsLv7NbmvTCQnwMR/zm@FNc7hwPgxPSvOqFRIyZZy3EutXQlqn9AU01tI1yCU4L1JCwvMof0urSsXRvgup/XTkyuhoea4x7NfzcxEWA6U9cKM9CmMZLCnqwRh3BEIcj/CGzsAHOjkJqoRotUIGSTypY1jpW6uBllg5SdNN32wLw@ouzkkBeb5fdwxuWg9ZBnu@IEstqvRXdW/btXj/iLBk/DWouQrb5gIHOLGfcCnpCRmnV6PSUUxm2J0ZQw5dR0@U0U9TIe1ZR1/C5SvA9f2MR@57/I8qoIQP4jvn0k4SkIbhBg

Comment: a si perdon que raro, es que yo usaba este programa para ejecutarlo https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: nose que habrá pasado pero en ese que me enviaste funciona bien, me toca pasarlo a codeblock y implementarlo en mi codigo , muchas gracias mas bien buenas noches

Comment: apenas lo implemente y vea que funcione te doy la puntuacion muchas griacas

Answer (score 3):

Recordá que los índices de un contenedor, en este caso matriz, empiezan a contar desde cero. Y de paso te digo que las declaraciones de funciones se escriben antes de la función main(), y las definiciones después de ésta.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

string verificarIdentificacion(string[2][2], int, string, string);

int main(){
    string matriz[2][2] = {{"1","hola"},{"3","que"}};
    int contador=0;
    string encontrado = "false";
    string existe = verificarIdentificacion(matriz,contador,"1",encontrado);
    cout<<existe<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

string verificarIdentificacion(string matriz[2][2], int contador, string identificacion, string encontrado){
    if(contador <2){
        if(matriz[contador][0] == identificacion){
            encontrado = "true";
            cout<<matriz[contador][0]<<endl;
        }else{
            verificarIdentificacion(matriz,contador+1,identificacion,encontrado);
        }
    }
    return encontrado;
}
```

Comment: funciona con 1, pero ahora tira falso cuando busco el 3